# Is there a clean way to add query string parameters to Rails link_to path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a path that links to a Rails controller at: */billings/roster/123?ocap_id=456*, where 123 is the roster_id and I'm passing in the ocap_id to the controller.

In my view, I can do:

`<%= link_to('Roster', billings_roster_path(roster_id) + "?ocap_id=#{ocap_id}" %>`

adding that query string to me seems a bit hacky, is there a Rails way to add `ocap_id: ocap_id` somehow?  I've searched the link_to documentation but they all show ways to do it without a path parameter, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Executive summary: `billings_roster_path(roster_id, ocap_id: ocap_id)`

Comment: Any keyword that doesn't corresponding to a named segment or one of the options such as `format` is added as a query string parameter.